# gnuplot arguments in a Homebrew installation

Tags: installation, arguments, gnuplot, homebrew

Upon installing *gnuplot* on my Mac with *Homebrew* I noticed that it passes many arguments to the `configure` file. More precisely, this is the output I was getting on the terminal

```
$ brew install gnuplot
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/4.6.3/gnuplot-4.6.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gnuplot-4.6.3.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/4.6.3 --with-readline=/usr/local/opt/readline --with-gd=/usr/local/opt/gd --disable-wxwidgets --without-cairo --without-latex --without-tutorial
```

Then I understood why what I had on my *Mac* was such a *poorer* version of what I have on my *Ubuntu*. Therefore, browsing the net I found that for being able to use the `wxt` terminal I need to add the `--wx` flag for the installation. Moreover it was suggested to use also `--pdf` and `--with-x`. Visually parsing the output I had on screen (which I pasted above), I made up other flags, such as `--cairo` and `--tutorial`, and I got the following output

```
$ brew install gnuplot --wx --cairo --pdf --with-x --tutorial
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/4.6.3/gnuplot-4.6.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gnuplot-4.6.3.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/4.6.3 --with-readline=/usr/local/opt/readline --with-pdf=/usr/local/opt/pdflib-lite --with-gd=/usr/local/opt/gd --without-latex --without-tutorial
==> make
==> make install
�  /usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/4.6.3: 49 files, 5.4M, built in 37 seconds
```

Now my question is: where the heck could I find a list of acceptable arguments to use for a *Homebrew* installation, such as the one here for *gnupot*? Moreover, somehow it didn't accept my `--tutorial` :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can run `brew options <formula>` to get the list of options for a given formula. For example, for gnuplot:

```
$ brew options gnuplot
```

Comment: Hence: brew install gnuplot --with-cairo